# Find bone-system given a mesh

Tags: animation, machine-learning

Animation newbie here. Usually, how do people call the process of finding the bone-based system corresponding to given mesh? I'm looking for machine-learning-based solutions that could improve the process.

Comment: "Finding" a bone-based system implies that one already exists in the first place. Perhaps you are talking about the process of *creating* a bone rig and linking it to the mesh?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for your clarification! Yes, creating a bone rig and linking it to the mesh is a great description of what I'm looking into. Does this set of actions have a specific name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of creating bones for a 3d model and linking vertices of the mesh to those bones so they can be animated is usually called "[rigging](https://conceptartempire.com/what-is-rigging/)".